# How to rename column with dplyr where both the new column name and the original column name are variables

Tags: r, dplyr

This kind of question is difficult to search for here, though I've tried.

```
library(dplyr)
target = "Species"

rename_data <- function(iris, target = "Species", new_target_name = "Spec3") {

  iris2 <- iris %>% rename(new_target_name = target)
  iris2
}

head(rename_data(iris))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width new_target_name
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2          setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2          setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2          setosa
```

I expect `Species` to rename to `Spec3`, not `new_target_name`.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you need the names to be stored as character variables (as shown) or do you actually want them to be supplied as function arguments?

Comment: I'd like the `Species` column to change to `Spec3`, but I don't want to hardcode it like `rename(Spec3 = Species)`.  I want to pass in the new name and old name as variables

Comment: please note that there is a difference between setting something as a global variable at the start of a script (as you are doing here) and writing a function that accepts arguments. you would want quo or enquo respectively

Comment: thanks the other answer helped.  This answer seems to work inside and outside a function.  dont really know why it works but it does

Comment: You can do this in base R `names(iris)[names(iris) == target] <- new_target_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided offered insight to the solution

```
rename_data <- function(iris, target = "Species", new_target_name = "Spec3") {
  iris2 <- iris %>% rename(!!new_target_name := target)
  iris2
}

head(rename_data(iris))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` like this:

```
 library(data.table)
 target = "Species"

 new_target_name = "Spec3"

 iris2 <- setnames(iris, old=target, new =new_target_name)
 head(iris2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a data.table solution

Comment: May I ask why? dplyr is notoriously bad for this sort of thing imho